# Sony Xperia Flash tool 'Emma'

Tags: sony

Last week I downloaded the [Flash tool](http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/flash-tool/), provided by Sony, from the developers world website and registered myself as a new user after installation.
However, my account doesn't seem to get validated. I don't receive any e-mails saying that they can't validate my account, nor any e-mails saying that they have.

Does anybody know anything about this validation process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to register or get validated.

Visit the link for more information.

http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/flash-tool/how-to-download-and-install-the-flash-tool/

Answer (score 4):

You haven't followed the installation guide properly. I beleive you have skipped the 5th step.

5.Paste the Customization.ini file into the installation folder. The installation folder is the folder named Emma in the installation path examples on point 3.1 and 3.2 above.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the software run it being in online mode and let the app update over the air, when update is complete it will ask for registration, this time you need to close the app, and follow these steps:-

A. Copy the Customization.ini file. You find it in the Flash_tool_for_Xperia_X.zip.

B. Paste the Customization.ini file into the installation folder. The installation folder is the folder named Emma in the installation path.
    for examples:-

a. Default path in Windows 64 bit is: “C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony Mobile\Emma\”

b. Default path in Windows 32 bit is: “C:\Program Files\Sony Mobile\Emma\

C. Come online and run the app by "Click Start > All programs > Sony Mobile > Emma (if you used the default installation path from step B above) to start the flash tool."
 all set, run the app..

Regards,

Priyank Abhineet.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed correct! just place the .ini file next to the .exe and no registration is being asked for ! 
But not all Sony devices are supported.

E1 is unsupported.